# A conjecture about comparing determinants of two Toeplitz matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and denote $m=(p-1)/2$. Let $\mathbb F_p$ be the finite field of order $p$. My question is about comparing determinants of two matrices over the polynomial ring $\mathbb F_p[a,\lambda]$ where $a$ and $\lambda$ are two free indeterminates.

**The first matrix** is of size $m\times m$ given by
\begin{equation}
A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
\delta_m & \ddots & \delta_{p-3} & \delta_{p-2} \\
\ddots & \delta_{m} & \ddots & \delta_{p-3} \\ 
\delta_2 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
\delta_1 & \delta_2 & \ddots & \delta_{m} \\
\end{array}\right)\end{equation}
where $\delta_n = \frac{\lambda^p(1-a^p)-(\lambda^p-a^p)\lambda^n}{n}$ for $1\leq n\leq p-2$.

**The second matrix** is of size $(m+1)\times(m+1)$ given by

\begin{equation}
B = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
\gamma_m & a^p\gamma_{3m} & \ddots & a^p\gamma_{2m+2}&  a^p\gamma_{2m+1} \\
\gamma_{m+1} & \gamma_{m} & a^p\gamma_{3m} & \ddots &  a^p\gamma_{2m+2} \\
\ddots & \gamma_{m+1} & \gamma_{m} & \ddots &  \ddots \\
\gamma_{2m-1} & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & a^p\gamma_{3m} \\
\gamma_{2m} & \gamma_{2m-1} & \ddots & \gamma_{m+1} & \gamma_{m} \\
                               \end{array}\right)\end{equation}
where $\gamma_n$'s are given by
$$x^m(x-1)^m(x-\lambda)^m = \gamma_mx^m + \gamma_{m+1}x^{m+1}+\cdots + \gamma_{3m}x^{3m}.$$

I guess:

**Conjecture 1:**
$$\det(A) = c\lambda^{m^2}(\lambda-1)^{m^2}\det(B).$$
where
\begin{equation}
c = (-1)^m\det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac1m & \frac1{m+1} & \cdots & \frac1{p-2}\\
\frac1{m-1} & \frac1{m} & \cdots & \frac1{p-3}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac1{1} & \frac1{2} & \cdots & \frac1{m}\\
\end{array}\right)\end{equation}

**Remark:** The conjecture holds for $p<50$. This was checked by using computer.